# WPF: IsPressed trigger of ControlTemplate not working

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, controltemplate

I use a custom control named `ImageButton` to display a button with different images. `ImageButton` contains dependency properties:

```
public ImageSource DisabledImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(DisabledImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisabledImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }


    public ImageSource NormalImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(NormalImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NormalImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource HoverImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(HoverImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HoverImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource PushedImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(PushedImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PushedImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisabledImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DisabledImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata());


    public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NormalImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata());


    public static readonly DependencyProperty HoverImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HoverImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PushedImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PushedImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata());
```

It's style is defined as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Name="image" Source="{Binding NormalImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stretch="None" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                    
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source" Value="{Binding DisabledImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source"  Value="{Binding PushedImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source" Value="{Binding HoverImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Every thing works fine except `IsPressed`. I can never see the image I set in `PushedImageSource` and I can't figure out why. 
Any help would be appriciated :)

### EDIT 1:

Here's the xaml code that tests it

```
<Window x:Class="SMEClient.WPF.Tester.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:is="clr-namespace:Project1.SearchBox;assembly=Project1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Project1;component/SearchBox/ImageButton.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <is:ImageButton NormalImageSource="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"
                            PushedImageSource="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg"
                            HoverImageSource="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Jellyfish.jpg"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: just try `IsPressed` instead of `Button.IsPressed` might work for you.

Comment: @NeelBhasin Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: can i see your xaml code for this?

Comment: @NeelBhasin uploaded it ...

Comment: What if you remove the 'TargetType="{x:Type Button}"' or change it to ImageButton?

Comment: Need to redefine the style by flipping this position of `IsPressed` and `IsMouseOver` with each other

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your triggers are not mutual exclusive, in this case the order in which triggers are added to the `Triggers` collection comes into play. Your last trigger `IsMouseOver` overrides the `Source` property after `IsPressed` trigger setts the correct image, since a button is Pressed only if the mouse is over (when using mouse of course).

Try setting the `IsPressed` trigger last in the `Triggers` collection, and the `IsPressed` trigger will be applied even though `IsMouseOver` is also true.

Comment: Wow! good catch :) didn't think about that possibility. Thanks! :)

Comment: Would not have guessed in a million years . Thank you.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I would never have imagined that the order of the triggers would affect his behavior.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found a workaround which is kind of ugly, but it works

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Name="Normal" Source="{Binding NormalImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stretch="None" Visibility="Visible" />
                    <Image Name="Hover" Source="{Binding HoverImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stretch="None" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    <Image Name="Clicked" Source="{Binding PushedImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stretch="None" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    <Image Name="Disabled" Source="{Binding DisabledImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stretch="None" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Hover" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Clicked" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Disabled" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Hover" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Clicked" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Disabled" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Hover" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Clicked" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Disabled" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: It doesn't make too much sense that this IsPressed trigger works, and the one you did in the question doesn't. It's exactly the same (beside the "Button.", but you said you tried it that way and it didn't work).

Comment: @user2760623 You are right. The problem wasn't with the `IsPressed` itself but with the order it was added to the triggers collection like @NovitchiS suggested. I'll still leave this answer here as it does work but I've marked @NovitchiS answer's as the solution.