# Button having an outer image and inner image in WPF- inner image not getting shown

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, controltemplate

I am trying to create a wpf button which has three bitmaps, 
1. Normal image
2. Hovering Image
3. Pressed Image.

I used the code given in the below for that.

[WPF: IsPressed trigger of ControlTemplate not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237890/wpf-ispressed-trigger-of-controltemplate-not-working)

Now i need to have this bitmap button contain an inner image and text.

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <loc:ImageButton Margin="10"  Width="150" Height="186" NormalImageSource="Images\tile.png" HoverImageSource="Images\tile_overlay_hovered.png" PushedImageSource="Images\tile_overlay_pressed.png">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="142"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="44"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source="Images\InnerImage.png" Width="70" Stretch="Uniform" Height="70" Margin="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Name" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </loc:ImageButton>


    </Grid>
```

My style xaml.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Name="image" Source="{Binding NormalImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stretch="None" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source"  Value="{Binding HoverImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source"  Value="{Binding PushedImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Unfortunately, I could not make the inner image nor the text to be displayed? Any kind of pointers will be appreciated. Is there something wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 1):

The content you add to your button will only show if you include a contentpresenter in the controltemplate. I do not know what you expect the button to look like but this control template will show your grid with the inner image to the right of the outer image.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Name="image" Source="{Binding NormalImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stretch="None" />
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source"  Value="{Binding HoverImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source"  Value="{Binding PushedImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I had gone with VisualStateManager which solved this problem.

Comment: Then you should post your solution